# New to Angular - Computed Variables

Tags: angularjs

I am moving to Angular from Knockout, and I have a few issues. I'm assuming that I must be doing something a non-angular type of way.

http://jsfiddle.net/LostInDaJungle/BxELP/

```
I linked to jsfiddle so I didn't have to include my code here
Stack Overflow will not let me post my question without a code block.
```

Here is a very basic fiddle that outlines two of my major problems...

Problem 1: val1 and val2 are initialized as 3 and 4, and add up to 7 properly. However, if you change either of the values in the text boxes, the new value is treated as a string and I get concatenation instead of addition. Change val1 to 4 and you get 44 when it should be 8. What is the best way around this behaviour?

Problem 2: Calculated fields. I can get a calculated field by using the curly brackets like {{val1 + val2}} and have the calculated fields auto update when the underlying model changes, but this is totally unacceptable. In my full fledged app, we generate a "cost" that is used several times throughout and having to put in the cost calculation each and every time is a pain. Not to mention that when this calculation changes, I now have the unenviable task of finding 15 different places that use the cost calculation and updating them all.

In addition, if I try to put an ng-model="cost" on the input with the curly brackets, then the curly brackets don't work. So nothing jumps out at me as a way to bind cost.

http://jsfiddle.net/LostInDaJungle/QNVwe/

This example is more like the structure I desire. However, unlike a ko.observable, the calculated fields do not update when the values that generate them change. The boilerplate solution everyone has foisted on me is to write a bunch of ng-change handlers... But that is awful. If width changes change the cost and change the payback calculations, etc... It quickly becomes a tangled mess.

Both of these methods fail as far as separating logic from presentation. Method one has my business logic embedded in my HTML. Method two puts a whole bunch of ng-change handlers in my code which isn't that much different from having to write a whole mess of onChange handlers in plain ol' HTML. If I HAVE to do a bunch of ng-change handlers, I would just as soon do an onChange handler in Javascript because I can at least declare them outside of my presentation layer.

Here's a knockout version of the same:

http://jsfiddle.net/LostInDaJungle/eka4S/2/

This is more like what I would expect... Nothing but data-binds on my inputs, all program logic nicely contained within the view model. Also, since my computable is a Javascript function, I don't have to scratch my head about how to ensure my two values are numeric.

So....

Computed variables: Is there a way to watch the underlying variables and update the computed amount automatically? Without having to bury my program logic in my HTML?

Is there a good way to keep my numbers from turning into strings?

Thank you for your help.

FYI, also posted to Google Groups: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/0dfnDTaj8tw

Comment: as an alternative to computed properties in this case, if you change the input type from text to number, it should work as expected

Comment: If you do not feel the tag edit was appropriate, you can roll it back. It seems to be a bit of an overreaction to want to delete a good question with its good answers over a single tag edit. Stack Overflow is a community-edited resource, and occasionally people make edits like this to clean up or add what they believe to be relevant tags. I don't see how anyone could possibly think this reflects poorly on you.

Answer (score 31):

For a calculated field, add a method to your controller . . .

```
$scope.cost = function() { return $scope.val1 + $scope.val2 };
```

and then bind to it directly.  It will know when it needs to recalculate as its constituent values change.

```
<div>{{cost()}}</div>
```

Comment: That just causes the code to not work: http://jsfiddle.net/LostInDaJungle/vqdSz/2/

Comment: Using ngModel on an input field won't make sense if referring to a calculation, since it's a method and not a writable property.  The fixed jsFiddle provided by romario333 will stop recalculating properly as soon as you manually try entering a value into the "sum" input (which doesn't really make sense to let the user do anyway).

Comment: This is incorrect, unless I am missing something: it wont recalculate when its constituents change, it will recalculate on every digest cycle, so if you have expensive calculations it will bog down performance, unlike knockout that knows exactly when to recalculate, ie when the constituent values change

Answer (score 13):

Ok,

A few hours later and I think I have my answer.

Using $scope.$watch.

```
$scope.$watch('(height * width) * 40', function(v) {$scope.cost = v;});
```

or

```
$scope.$watch('height + width', function() {$scope.cost = (Number(height) * Number(width)) * 40;});
```

This auto-updates any computables for watched variables. And it gives me a way to work with these without having to live inside curly brackets.

Also, the computed values can be reused and tracked for cascading updates:

```
$scope.$watch('height * width', function(v) {$scope.dim = v;});
$scope.$watch('dim * 40', function(v) {$scope.cost = v;});
```

So if height and/or width change, dim is updated, and since dim has changed, cost is updated.

Comment: You're right, Jason, that will work.  However, I'm not sure that it's canonical Angular.  Since your intent for the dim and cost variables is to represent a calculation (and not be writable), isn't it more clear to implement them as a method?  I personally find it helpful to distinguish "values that are supposed to be changed" from "values that are calculated;" a controller method for the latter might reduce confusion.

Comment: I'm all up for learning best practices, but I'm not sure what you're saying. This is very similar to what I have done in Knockout for years `self.dim = ko.computed(function () {return self.height() * self.width();})`  I'm still learning, but the official docs don't get into this, so I'm having to figure it out as I go along. So maybe I'm guilty of treating everything like a nail.

Answer (score 6):

I changed your third input to:

```
<input type="text" value="{{val1 * 1 + val2}}" />
```

which causes Angular.js to treat the values as numbers, not strings.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QNVwe/3/). I gleaned the answer from [here](http://rabidgadfly.com/2012/12/angularjs-simple-calculator/).

Comment: Still has the problem that my logic is tied up in my HTML. That does retype them as numbers, I just don't want whomever inherits my job to be reading that thinking "What did that idiot intend here?"

Comment: You're absolutely right, that looks messy in the HTML.  One suggestion - in the controller:

    $scope.total = function() {return ($scope.val1 * 1) + $scope.val2;};

in the HTML:

    <input type="text" value="{{total()}}" />

Comment: In the controller I can use Number($scope.val1) instead of the * 1 which has an ambiguous purpose.

Answer (score 2):

**About problem 1:**

You should use input type="number" if possible. That would take care of parsing numbers properly. Even if you have an older browser angular would take care of formatting them as numbers.

**About problem 2:**

Your answer is good Jason if you just need to show plain text on the screen. However if you would like to bind an input with a model to an arbitrary expression, you need something else.

I wrote a directive you can use to bind an ng-model to any expression you want. Whenever the expression changes the model is set to the new value.

```
module.directive('boundModel', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.boundModel, function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if(newValue != oldValue) {
          ngModel.$setViewValue(newValue);
          ngModel.$render();
        }
      });
    }
  };
})
```

You can use it in your templates like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="total" bound-model="value1 + value2">
```

Or like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="total" bound-model="cost()">
```

Where cost() is a simple function of the scope like this:

```
$scope.cost = function() { return $scope.val1 + $scope.val2 };
```

The good thing is that you keep using a model for your input and you don't have to dinamically update your value attribute, which doesn't work well in angular.

Comment: Solution 1: My view should not be controlling my Model. I should be binding data in HTML, not typing it.

Solution 2: That is totally unnecessary. The point of this post was to learn to do things the "right" angular way. I already had a workaround that was posted in the OP. I didn't want to rely on workarounds.

Comment: Just my two cents, I know most people consider the angular way to put all logic in a controller. I make heavy use of directives and services and most of the time I have views packed with directives that do simple things or even bind directly to services. I find it much easier to reuse directives across templates and also understand more easily what's happening just looking in one place, which is the template. Most controllers I write end up being small directive controllers that do one thing well, and my route controllers are much smaller, even non existent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to AngularJS but I think that $parse could be used:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse

This is interesting if you have the expression as a string. You can use a path of properties and that string can be generated dynamically. This works if you don't know the expression at compile time, a lot like eval() but probably a lot faster and maybe more secure(?).

Here's an example:

```
function Ctrl($scope,$parse) {
  var expression = 'model.val1 + model.val2';//could be dynamically created
  $scope.model = {
    val1: 0,
    val2: 0,
    total: function() { 
        return ($parse(expression))($scope); 
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u can bind to a function

```
function CTRL ($scope) {
$scope.val1 = 3;
$scope.val2 = 4;
$scope.sum = function(){
   return ($scope.val1 *1 + $scope.val2 *1);
};
```

}

it will work the same 
the binding expression will work but in much more complex cases we need functions

Answer (score 0):

The $watch function that is made available through the $scope variable is best for this job in my opinion.

```
$scope.$watch(function(scope) { return scope.data.myVar },
              function(newValue, oldValue) {
                  document.getElementById("myElement").innerHTML =
                      "" + newValue + "";
              }
             );
```

The $watch function takes in a:
value function
& a listener function

The above example is taken from this awesome article: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/watch-digest-apply.html

After reading through it, I learnt a lot and was able to implement the solution I was looking for.